# Create a ModelView xamarin

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, model-view

It's a example app, have a Entry and Label, write a Entry number and the label write the same number.

I want aply MVVM model, but I don't understand what I need to do.

I don't know to create the ModelView.

In my code I have:

Model Persona, is Person whith atribute int age;`namespace HolaMVVM.Models
{
    class Persona
    {
        private int _edad;

```
    public Persona()
    {
        _edad = 0;
    }
    public int Edad
    {
        get { return _edad; }
        set
        {
            _edad = value;
        }
    }
}
```

View MainView.xaml

```
  <StackLayout>
    <Entry
      Text="{Binding Edad, Mode=TwoWay}"
      VerticalOptions="Center"
      HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
   <Label Text="{Binding Edad}" 
       VerticalOptions="Center"
       HorizontalOptions="Center" />
 </StackLayout>
```

and MainView.xaml.cs

```
    public partial class MainView : ContentPage
{
    public MainView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
}
```

But I don't know Binding person atributes to View

```
    class MainViewModel : BindableObject
{
    private Persona persona;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        persona = new Persona();
    }
}
```

TANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggests to take a look to [Introduction to MVVM](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/Introduction-to-MVVM)

and use [PropertyChanged.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged)

Your Persona should implement INotifyPropertyChanged (with Fody...)

In your ViewModel you should have a "`public Persona persona {get;set;}`"

then in your XAML you can bind something like `{Binding persona.Edad}`

these are the "basics", then watch @jamesmontemagno video